# How to apply mix-blend-mode while keeping text opaque?

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

I need some help recreating this in CSS (if possible) :

[image: this]

And here is what I have so far:

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501706362039-c06b2d715385?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1070&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 100px 50px;
}

.text {
  background: #ed1c24;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.text p {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      These artistic movements were a refelection of the million of people who lived and worked here. To them, "I ❤ NY" could be read as a rallying cry.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a div with a background image and overlaying that div is another one with a red bg color and `mix-blend-mode: multiply` on it. It looks like the color blend is working correctly, but is there a way that I can make the white text be unaffected and an opaque solid white like in the example image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use pseudo element and apply `mix-blend-mode: multiply` on it like this :

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501706362039-c06b2d715385?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1070&q=60&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 100px 50px;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
}

.text:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ed1c24;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text p {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      These artistic movements were a refelection of the million of people who lived and worked here. To them, "I ❤ NY" could be read as a rallying cry.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```